# Forces acting on a SC-MagLev train

Tags: magnets

SC-MagLev trains are comprised of superconducting magnetic loops. The electromagnets on the outside that propel them as well are current-carrying magnetic loops. How can we calculate the force between the two?

Also, could a MagLev train of such kind loop on a circular track? I'm assuming it can, and it's just by applying more force on one side than the other, so it ever so slightly turns toward the desired direction. Is my reasoning correct? If not, what according to you is right?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you done any research? maglev train in Japan and another in Germany.

Comment: Yes, but I could find no formula or anything of that sort to find the force that acts between the two loops. All I could find was some double loop integration, and my mathematical skills are not that advanced, so I was hoping to find a simpler answer. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572395/force-between-parallel-current-carrying-loops this is what I'm talking about. Could you please explain what this means? Thanks a lot for responding that quick!